# Why can't Kakashi use Lightning Cutter properly after losing his Sharingan?

Tags: naruto

Is Kakashi's new technique *Lightning Release: Purple Electricity* as powerful as his signature technique, the *Lightning Cutter*?

On [Naruto Wiki](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Kakashi_Hatake), it is written that after losing his Sharingan, Kakashi can't use Lightning Cutter **properly**. What does this mean?

Comment: Because of his sharingan Kakashi he had more chakra, which means that his techniques used too much chakra. Remember when Naruto asked about the difference between him and Kakashi, he said it's 4 times smaller but this with his Sharingan. So he is not able not only to make that much chakra he cannot also create it propetly, because of that. Also I am not sure about that, but if someone copied some techniques through Sharingan maybe they can't do them again because they don't have this eyes?

Comment: the sharigan drained chakra from him, not ggave him a larger chakra pool

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kakashi can't use the Lightning Cutter because it creates tunnel vision without the Sharingan, leaving him open for counter-attacks.

Comment: So does it mean that he still *can* use Lightning Cutter but doesn't do so in fighting because it puts him at a disadvantage?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: If not already seen, please do watch Kakashi - Gaiden , in which Minato explains that the Raikiri is an incomplete technique to a young kakashi [who did not have the sharingan then]

Answer (score 0):

Well if you recall from the fillers where Kakashi first used Raikari, he got his eye scared because he couldn't handle the speed of his body. When you use raikari it speeds your movement due to the Lighting Chakra and if you don't have sharingan to go with you(for seeing your opponents attacks from a longer range) or a lightining shield(like the raikage's have) you are in for open attacks. That's why Kakashi couldn't use the Raikari without the sharingan.